# Wrapped service

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-integration

I've been reaching wrapped services examples for java and spring and I cannot find anything useful. There are plenty of tutorials for java and spring web services but nothing on wrapped ones

Basically if given 2 wsdls, how can I create a wrapped service? I am hoping there are working examples or even a nice start to finish tutorial to help me out.

Comment: Please define "wrapped service". If you found nothing about it, it's probably because you're the only one to use that terminology.

Comment: A web service that makes use of other web services.

Comment: A web service A that calls another web service B is a client of the web service B, like any other client of a web service. If your tutorial describes how to write a client of a web service, then it has what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

i think what you're looking for is like a 'federated service' or a 'business delegate' pattern.  that is, one WSDL showing all the methods for the other two WSDL's combined.

one way of doing this is using Spring Integration.  with Spring Integration you could expose your 'consolidated' WSDL and then route the various methods to the specific correct actual endpoints.  have a look at [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/ws.html) in the Spring Integration documents about exposing a webservice and then subsequently routing and invoking others.